# Japanese language for directions in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, localization

I am using Android 4.0 and latest version of Google Maps. The interface is in English. When I search for direction to some place say Kyoto, the interface is in mixed English and Japanese. See the attached screenshot to understand what I mean.

[image: Screenshot]

How do see the destination names in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get it in English. You will always get the text as it is "locally". It's also a [known annoyance](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/dxcN3YowkEo).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Morelocale 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale&hl=en) and setting the locale to one of the English speaking countries or yet better define a new locale with language en and locale JP.